# Indenting wrapped words in tabular environment

Tags: tables, indentation

How do I indent wrapped words in a tabular environment?

I would like my table to look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| heading 1 | heading 2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| cell 1    | cell 2    |
+-----------+-----------+
| cell 3    | Wrapped   |
|           |   words   |
|           |   with    |
|           |   indent. |
+-----------+-----------+
| cell 4    | cell 5    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `\hangindent`.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{3in}}
hello & \hangindent=2em\lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax is

```
\hangindent=<dim>
```

**Addendum**

To get this to apply to entries in the second column, you can use the `array` package and then use the prefix notation `>{\handindent=2em}` before declaring the column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\hangindent=2em}p{4in}}
hello & \lipsum[1] \\
hello & \lipsum[2] \\
hello & \lipsum[3] 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Other similar commands**

Other useful commands along these lines are:

```
\hangafter=<num>
```

Here `<num>` can be a positive or negative number.  `<num>` specifies how many lines are to be indented.  A negative value indicates that the indentation is applied to the first `<num>` lines.  A positive value indicates that the indentation is applied to the lines `<num+1>`, `<num+2>`,...

```
\parshape <num>
          <indent> <length>
          ...
          <indent> <length>
```

Here `<num>` indicates how many lines the `\parshape` applies to.  `<indent>` indicates how much the *nth* line should be indented.  `<length>` indicates how wide the line is to be.  There should be as many `<indent> <length>` pars has `<num>`.  Once the first `<num>` lines have been formatted, the remaining lines, if any, will retain the formatting of the last line.

Here's a solution to your problem using `\parshape`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{3in}}
hello & \parshape 2 
                  0pt 3in 
                  2em \dimexpr3in-2em\relax 
                  \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Finally, here's an example using `\hangafter` (not quite the effect you want, but nevertheless a possibility):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{3in}}
hello & \hangindent=2em
        \hangafter=3
        \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The my problem was that I put "\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1" only in front of my table's first column entries, thinking it would apply to all the columns.

Comment: Is there a way to make ""\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1" apply automatically to each cell, so I don't have to keep repeating "\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1" all over the place? thanks

Comment: @Geremia I've updated my answer to show how to apply this format to all entries in a particular column.

Comment: I don't have enough privilege to correct a one-character typo: `>{\handindent=2em}` should be `>{\hangindent=2em}`