# Automatic indentation in tabularx after line break

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx, indentation

Similary to this [How do I get indentation after automatic line break?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466880/how-do-i-get-indentation-after-automatic-line-break) after breaking (automatically, or manually with `\newline`) lines in a tabularx environment I would like to obtain an automatic indentation of the second, new line.

So something like

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
Some very long text here such that it spreads over the whole textwidth and even beyond. LaTeX will automatically break the line at some point but lets say we do it manually here \newline
then THIS part should be indented by, idk, 5pt. (should also happen when tabularx breaks the line automatically)
\end{tabularx}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Only the secon line, or all lines after the first?

Comment: Does `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hangindent=5pt}X}` result in the expected output?

Comment: `\newline\hspace*{5pt}%` or `\par\hspace{5pt}%`.  However, if you were willing to settle for just post-paragraph (not linebreak) indents, then start out cell with `\parindent5pt\noindent`

Comment: Changing `X` to  `>{\hangafter=1\hangindent=5pt}X` should work. See, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248916/5001 for more information

Comment: @leandriis That did exactly what I wanted, thanks! Will give you credit when you write an answer.

Comment: @Tork: Since your question is quite similar to  [Indenting wrapped words in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135557/indenting-wrapped-words-in-tabular-environment) I've just voted to close yours as a duplicate to the previously mentioned one.